# IPhone Core Data Backup Restore Testing Questions

Tags: ios, core-data, backup, restore

I'm in the learning stages of IOS development and have a few questions based on some behavior I recognized on my initial testing.
My questions for now will be related to a local ITunes backup.

For one thing, does an app that is not "certified" (an app under development and testing) supposed to get backed up on ITunes? On ICloud?  And what about it's core data?  I ask this because I watched as it backed up other apps, but not my test app in the progress bar.

Bottom line is, I want to test how a user of my app's [core] data will or will not be restored under 2 situations as follows.

1. The user drops his phone in a lake and needs to do a COMPLETE RESTORE on a new device
2. The user deletes my app (after having backed up), then later wants to reinstall the app.

Through a few different iterations, I can not get my app's data back after an app removal and reinstall.

I would like to test this under both local and ICloud backup.  From what I can understand, you are not given the option to see what files/apps are backed up and available to restore.  Furthermore you are not able to restore individual apps/data? Or am I missing something?

I have not done anything special in terms of "designing for ICloud backup/restore or syncing".  I want all data to be available ONLY locally as it is and is currently working great.

I guess my biggest question for the moment is "Are development apps treated like certified apps in the backup and restore processes?"

There is a lot of information out there but it is all rather convoluted.  Plus it appears an ICloud backup/restore and an Itunes backup/restore are 2 different animals? Thanks for any guidance.

BTW, I can see the app in the Backup Options, and Backup? is set to yes, however after I backup and look on ITunes, I see all the other apps except my test app.